# How to extend a style inherited from a parent container in an UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a `StackPanel` with a `UserControl` inside:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyUC/>
</StackPanel>
```

The `UserControl` contains various `TextBoxes` and other controls that have their styles set via a `ResourceDictionary`, to achieve a common look all over the application.
For the `TextBox`es, the `ResourceDictionary` entry looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
</Style>
```

Now I would like to apply a default style in the parent control (the `StackPanel`) to all of the `TextBox`es inside the `UserControl`, so I can bind the `IsReadOnly`-property of the `TextBox`es to a property that is only available in the parents Model:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.State}" Value="ReadOnly">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <local:MyUC/>
</StackPanel>
```

Unfortunatly, the default style for the `TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"` that is defined inside of the `ResourceDictionary` of the `UserControl` overrides the style that I'm trying to set in the parent `StackPanel`.

How can I achieve to *extend* the default style that is defined inside the `StackPanel.Resources` with the default style defined in the `UserControl`s `ResourceDictionary` instead of overwriting it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do and I never have a problem:

In ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxBase" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!-- Default styles go here -->
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxBase}"/>
```

This ensures that unless otherwise specified, all TextBoxes will have the style `TextBoxBase` and nothing more/less.

When defining styles that must have the above properties and then some, you define the style (in your case, this style is part of the StackPanel) like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxBase}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- These triggers should be in ADDITION to triggers defined in TextBoxBase.-->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.State}" Value="ReadOnly">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Another issue could be the fact that your defining a style for TextBoxes contained in a control. If the TextBoxes you are targeting the style with are unique the control they are contained in, why not define them in the control itself? To do that, you simply bind a reference to your ViewModel on the control, then use that reference IN the control to apply the DataTrigger to each TextBox using the method above.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I ended up adding an additional ContainerControl just for the TextBoxes inside of the UserControl and bound it's IsReadOnly property to a generic ReadOnly-property available in my ViewModelBase. As I went pass the problem half a year ago, unfortunately I'm unable to test your solution right away, but will keep it in mind to give it a try as soon as I'll encounter the issue again.